# How do I use the Find command in windows command-line to match the first character only?

Tags: windows, command-line, find

For example if the dir command produces something like this:

```
> dir
file1.txt
file2.txt
another file3.txt
another file4.txt
```

I want to be able to filter all file names that start with the letter 'f'. Any ideas?

I've tried the following command but that returns ALL file names with an 'f' anywhere in the name:

```
>dir | find "f"
file1.txt
file2.txt
another file3.txt
another file4.txt
```

Unless I've missed something, the documentation [here](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/find.mspx) doesn't say how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation says:

> You cannot use wildcards (that is, *
>   and ?) in file names or extensions
>   that you specify with the find command

Try using [findstr](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/findstr.mspx?mfr=true) instead:

```
dir /B | findstr /b "s"
```

- I'm using `dir` with the `/B` option because I want the *Bare format (no heading, file sizes or summary)*
- `findstr /b` *Matches the pattern if at the beginning of a line*